# ASCII-Plot the equation

Tags: code-golf, math, ascii-art, polynomials

You are given a polynomial function, in the following format:

\$x = (c_0 * y^0) + (c_1 * y^1) + (c_2 * y^2) + ... + (c_n * y^n)\$

where \$c_n\$ stands for the coefficient of the \$n^{th}\$ power of \$y\$

You have to plot the equation on a \$10 * 10\$ ASCII matrix. The value must be **floored** to an integer before plotting. If \$y < 0\$ or \$y > 9\$, then do not plot. For simplicity, we are assuming the top left corner to be \$(0,0)\$.

A `.` represents an empty space, and `*` represents a point on the graph. You can choose any characters to represent both of the things as per your convenience but do mention what you use in your answer.

You may take the input as a list/array of coefficients, or, as a string in the above specified format.

Examples:

```
Input -> x = (1 * y^1)
Output ->
*.........
.*........
..*.......
...*......
....*.....
.....*....
......*...
.......*..
........*.
.........*

Input -> x = (9 * y^0) + (-1 * y^1)
Output ->
.........*
........*.
.......*..
......*...
.....*....
....*.....
...*......
..*.......
.*........
*.........

Input -> x = (0.10 * y^2)
Output ->
*.........
*.........
*.........
*.........
.*........
..*.......
...*......
....*.....
......*...
........*.

Input -> x = (3 * y^1)
*.........
...*......
......*...
.........*
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
```

*Hint: eval can be helpful here.*

Inspired by a clash of code problem from https://www.codingame.com/

Comment: Can we take the function as a black-box function?

Comment: I'm assuming the equation can be taken as a list of coefficients, or similar? Parsing the format shown in the test cases would be [unnecessarily involved, and quite likely overshadow the actual task in many languages](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19357/85334)

Comment: @unrelatedstring yes, the input can be taken as a list of coefficients. I have edited the question to include that

Comment: Can we return a Boolean matrix with trues indicating the points?

Comment: @Adam That seems reasonable

Comment: @Arnauld No worries.

Comment: _For simplicity, we are assuming the top left corner to be (0,0)_ If that's the requirement, fine; but I think _simplicity_ would be to let the answer choose where the origin is

Comment: The hint "eval can be helpful here" sounds like you want to allow answers to get values of the polynomial by assigning to `y` and then using eval on the input string. If so, could we substitute our language's operators for multiplication, addition, and exponentiation in place of `*`, `+`, and `^`? (In particular, `**` for exponentiation in Python.) What about substituting different syntax if our language doesn't use infix operators? E.g. `(0.10 * Math.pow(y, 2))` in JavaScript or `(* 0.10 (pow y 2))` in a Lisp dialect?

Comment: @Dlosc, yes you can replace it, but not in the input itself. also in javascript whats wrong with `(0.10 * y**2)`

Comment: I Literally had this idea a few hours ago

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 15 bytes

Full program. Takes list of coefficients in descending order. Returns Binary matrix. Requires 0-based indexing (`⎕IO←0`).

```apl
a∘.=⍨⌊⎕⊥⍨⍪a←⍳10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862gv@Jz7qmKFn@6h3xaOeLqDUo66lIHbvqkSgkke9mw0N/gOV/VcAgwIuQwUDLl1dXS4Y/9B6QwVLFBEDPUMDBQM0ZcYKBgA)

`⍳10` **i**ndices 0…9

`a←` store as `a`

`⍪` make into column vector

`⎕⊥⍨` prompt for coefficients and evaluate the them as digits in base each-element-of-`a`

`⌊` floor

`a∘.=⍨` equality table with `a` horizontally

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.polynomials`, 73 bytes

```
[ 10 iota dup -rot '[ _ polyval 1 /i _ [ = pprint ] with each nl ] each ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/NDsIgEITvfYrx5F@srZ7UeDZevBhPjRpSMRIpIKVqY3z2usUao8uFWb6dZY4sddpWm/VytZgi55eCq5TnONoSZ24Vl8iYO4VGy1LpTDCZ@waM5c6VxgrlIDRmQfAIQPVAhBhP@Grhjjk6MXood3G3ASYYfIgGmHggQr9@@WGj@oQeb1hSkWdGX2b8t3D8MXlWCQgX2jEcCoOB1Q7tBHvUga5M0l@HgmRCY@adZouboICcpScoSdLftuTkVaozo3Puu9UL)

Takes a sequence of coefficients from low to high. `polyval` handles the actual evaluation of the polynomial; the rest is just data plumbing and output.

`1 /i` is to convert from a float to integer, as it is shorter than `>integer` (and `floor` doesn't produce an integer in Factor [AND `1 /i =` is shorter than `number=` by 1 byte]). I found a locals solution that was the same length, but couldn't save any bytes. You can save 2 bytes by using a modern version of Factor with `tuck`, but meh.

Prints `t` for a point on the graph and `f` for empty space.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 15 bytes

*-2 thanks to Jonah!*

```
(<.@p.=/])i.@10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NWz0HAr0bPVjNTP1HAwN/mtypdtapSZn5DtoWKcBOUClhkDSUiHeEMwBQj0Iy/g/AA)

Execute the left function with `i.@10` (`0 1 2 … 9`) as the right argument.
`<.@p.` apply polynomial (thanks J for the built-in!) to each `i.@10`, floor and compare each result to `i.@10` with `=/`.

Comment: `(<.@p.=/])i.@10` for 15

Comment: @Jonah Huh. I knew that `g@noun f` works, but not that `f g@noun` works, too! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, basically `g@noun` is just shortcut for `g@(noun"_)` generally.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
Ｅχ⭆χ⁼λ⌊↨ιθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUDD0EBHIbgEyE2H8VwLSxNzijVydBTccvLzizScEotTNTJ1FAo1wcD6///oaAM9Qx0FoFqD2Nj/umU5AA) Takes input as a list of coefficients (in order of highest power of y down to 1) and outputs a binary matrix. Explanation:

```
 χ          Predefined variable 10
Ｅ           Map over implicit range
   χ        Predefined variable 10
  ⭆         Map over implicit range and join
         θ  Input coefficients
        ι   Outer index
       ↨    Evaluate polynomial
      ⌊     Floor
     λ      Inner index
    ⁼       Do they equal?
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>87 85 83</s>  81 bytes

Expects an array of coefficients, from lowest to highest.

```javascript
a=>(g=x=>y>9?'':`
*.`[x>9?x=++y-y:a.reduce((p,c,i)=>p+c*y**i)^x++?2:1]+g(x))(y=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcpBCoMwFATQvadw5/9JDNquFH48iFgMMYpFjGhbktOndluE2cybeeqPPsw@b698dYONI0VNCibypIKqmiyr@4TJvvVn8cR5yEOt5W6Ht7EAmzBiRlIbNywwNuPDc97c6rLjE3hECFRgNG493GLl4iYYoS1EWnaIyR9XIs2v/Lz/IsvieryfHL8)

#### Commented

```javascript
a => (                   // a[] = input array of coefficients
  g = x =>               // g is a recursive function taking x
  y > 9 ?                // if this is the end of the graph:
    ''                   //   stop the recursion
  :                      // else:
    `\n*.`[              //   lookup string: 0 = '\n', 1 = '*', 2 = '.'
      x > 9 ?            //   if this is the end of the row:
        x = ++y - y      //     increment y, set x to 0, yield 0
      :                  //   else:
        a.reduce(        //     compute P(y)
          (p, c, i) =>   //       which is the sum of all
          p + c * y ** i //       a[i] * y ** i
        ) ^ x++          //     test whether floor(P(y)) = x
        ? 2              //     and yield 2 if it's not
        : 1              //     or 1 if it is
    ] +                  //
    g(x)                 //   do a recursive call
)(y = 0)                 // initial call with x = y = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
éR▒Å╗←û%╞.A◄→⌐‼²GÑd,
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8252b18fbb1b9625c62e41111aa913fd47a5642c&i=%5B0,1%5D%0A%5B9,-1%5D%0A%5B0,0,0.1%5D%0A%5B0,3%5D&m=2)

Very long, partly due to `floor` not working on integers.

uses 1 and 0 as the display chars.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 112 bytes

```python
def f(l,*m):
 for x in range(10):
  try:m=[*m,[0]*10];m[x][int(sum(y*x**z for y,z in l))]=1
  except:1
 return m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY1BDoIwEEX3nKJhNdOMhMpKDCdpuiDaag0tpJQEuDxS3bkyYTf5897/wxKfva@27a4NM9ARd1hnzPSBzcx6Flr/0CDKFLIYlto1kjuSpeKiVFcnZyWtjzBODhY@c75@3IXWZHeIqhG7qeebHmK9n0HHKXjmtoR11uvEGZAgSKBKM0NIhXlevHrrwbUDjDFQQhEx@34x@9UvVCLB6WBLIeh8xK/@mt/e)

-15 bytes thanks to @UnrelatedString

-3 bytes thanks to @ophact

Comment: [Function submissions must be reusable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4940/85334), but mutating a list default argument renders this... [not](https://tio.run/##jc2xDsIgFAXQna946QSENMVuTfolhJhGQTGFEqAJ9OdRdNLJ5S333Pt8SffNjbVelQaNV2ZnIQZJ@aC3AGcwDsLibgrzgUgyIUihvC60NH@lkxVZCuMSjrvFhWZKjzcr7GhwJUTOHIHKF@XT5JcYEQSV9uDA1gZX41STGgs8Mv7550Ob7Lr@sRmH7eJxTIE1SghB6LfXc3b6o1if). I feel like there is some good way to golf that bit back down, but I'm too tired to think of better than:

Comment: https://tio.run/##pY1BDsIgFET3PQVx9T/BBuzKmp6EsGgUtKZQQmlSenkU3bky6XbmvRmf4mNyTc43bYiBkVGLbUXMFMhKBkdC7@4aBC8hiSG1tpPUMskVFVxdrFyVHFyEebGQ6Erp9nET24o9IqpOvE29XrWPre/nuSJBxyU4YnMhx8HpghqQIJhAVZ58KJuHQ/2cBge29zDHwAqKiNW3xepXPzOODI47V2rBTnv85q/7/AI

Comment: @UnrelatedString thanks!!!

Comment: except:1 instead of except:pass seems to work. Doesn’t do anything as the exp is evaluated

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>164</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>123</s></sup> 111 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att)!!!

```c
y;i;f(l,n,x)float*l,x;{for(y=-1;x=y++<9;i=x>=1&x<11?x:0,puts("         *"+10-i))for(i=n;i--;)x+=l[i]*pow(y,i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVTRbpswFH3PV1xZ6oTBdDhkD4lD8zDtK5K0YhR3ZhQizFSziF8fM4YEQjKtKkpC7HPOPedeLCL3JYqapmKCcSslGVGYp3lY2ilR7MjzwqoClzIVVI6zXjIRqIeAflJrSjdq5ZHDr1JaCE6XjRzquQLjViiCjAnXZVg5QboVe/uQv1kVEZjVjchKeA1FZuHZcdYqjSmUsSyf6HYPARw9ArRmU3DegUsC7g3UP0vbz/0NxuLM8MegbVDZgV0K0hv2d7@/L3pZ24HZyDqRFL/jnFudFn/ul3a/JjDG5xN8PsH9Ce5P8MUEX@A@VPQjLGz9G0c/40LngjYZ2qlv851aftXfL4jAeO2j0xTyAqy2J5E9x0rLPNb/XY@t5aWzxAwcx/AwdA9yNNJUl@nGahh7dia0RlmP6gFO4UOhCdxCbQ6EL2UhL@PiSZZhUZqUg@mpg6RLn@jkWRsvGUczZThY6TbZT/dPmC6gK9xCx@Hu/HvK9ThNJXZFrSFOZTzUo/@tJ01Fu9I1R01uTFR4AG@DwAG0QuDqoayQpvHwu@w6@XeAd5o@3j1/xJdAcsv6aufyqdFLyUCvr47AapeNT4B5R@HrkxIM1yCoZ3XzJ@Jp@CIb961x09e/)

Uses the space ( ) character for background and an asterisk (`*`) for plot points.

Comment: [123 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZLdToMwFMfv9xQNiYZCqxTwYnbVC@NTbIshCLOxKwuQrLjw6mJLuw3JGqAcfv/z0cPJ8S7Ph6GjnJa@QBIpWIoqawOBFD2VVe13DBOqWBeGqyXlTL0wcq9WhLyq5wgdai7b0vfuMImajfSQB84r8EISYQ6hCcKZpBxjClXIxJpvg0N19DvEIe0HHQHsMy59uDgtjOdYAGiLpv0g6y1g4BQhQHo6h7GFSwTwDZpcXM31cEORXhTJFAYjbSy0VSCX0O2J21PnZk4wfpDWqeE/RVX61hc@OjNwNgJTHs94POPJjCczns54Cl1R@VdWB/pZ5N9FresCpjJvo97jjVq@6fvJQ2BqJ965C1UNfHMmLj8Lpd0i6l5X09TN/8wNpCAMRx0E9kdOWip0GNvWUbGlF4FJJB3VDZzjcSrh1T5PHLsuPXdO0C/64TcvRbZrBnwcsNj/AQ)

Comment: @att Nice one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 86 bytes

```python
lambda l,r=range(10):[[i==sum(c*x**n for n,c in enumerate(l))//1for i in r]for x in r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU5LDoIwEN17igmrFiufsJKkJ6ldVGy1BgZSSoKnRwaUZBZv3m9m@MRXj9Xi5G1pTXd/GGhFkMHg07Ky4LVSXspx6liTzmmK4PoAKBrwCBanzgYTLWs5z/OSJE9C0ATnHS6Em946NxKhVCGg1ALUVcBlAytBk/2XSuv6BEPwGJlje5Tz03a69Wip5uBX58@aJNm798jUGAM7ew7HPxTS1LAb@fIF)

Takes a list of coefficients in ascending power. Outputs a list of lists of booleans.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 200 bytes

```hs
p[]x=0;p(s:r)x=x*p r x+s
q f=[[b$map(subtract y.p f)[x,x+1/4..x+3/4]|y<-n]|x<-n]
b=(['⠀'..]!!).a.map c
n=[0..9]
c x|x<0=[0,0]|x<0.5=[1,0]|x<1=[0,1]|x>0=[0,0]
a[[l,r]]=l*8+r*16
a([l,r]:s)=2*a s+l+r*8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDRTsIwFH3vVxwXEtcVyqZoYFrffTD63tSkjBIWyza2EYrhwU/x2/wR7ACNmnibtOeec0970oVuXoy1@30llRPxTRU2aU2dcFGFGo41ZIW5kHLaW2qvradtrbMWW15hTqXrO5YMR5w7djkcqd32dlConet2MhWhPP94fzvnXJ2dUa65vwEZKYSMOZ8oksH50di3/bgzxfxKyOSIk45NPLo76URLafu1UsJGY1ZHyTXR4YFJGyouIo2GWc@P90udF0hT3D8ipOTQCeRFaw7Be1gXNi9MA46sLDLdPvhUYWXL9qm026Jc5tp6rctaGz3zcFPWs4Z6cPARbBamNvjjyEoz99qpBILguwFShIGDCMDY6dEf4s@S8DN@mLFmUW6QMRYgwvb5izCeoME/5h1C088obgd4zSt0v6yOuaDorzSrI72PkZAJBgmJ4RfvzstP)

The function `q` takes a list of polynomial-coefficients and generates braille dot-matrix characters. Example:

```hs
x = + (0.0 * y^0) + (0.0 * y^1) + (0.1 * y^2)
⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⢱⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠈⡆⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠘⡄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠘⡄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠘⢄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠢⡀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠑⢄⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠑⢄
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
⁵ḶɓḅḞ=€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R49aHO7adnPxwR@vDHfNsHzWt@X@4PVIFSGc9atzHxfX/f7ShjoJBrI5CtC6QYQli6IFEoILGIBoA)

*-2 bytes because the output format was loosened, then I noticed another golf in the course of writing the explanation*

*-1 byte because why the hell didn't I already try that?*

Input as coefficients in descending order of power, output as binary matrix.

```
⁵Ḷɓ        Let [0 .. 9] be the right argument to the following dyadic link:
   ḅ       evaluate the polynomial at each y in [0 .. 9],
    Ḟ      and floor each result.
      €    For each result,
     =     is it equal to each x in [0 .. 9]?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>46</s> 43 bytes

```
0<=#<1&/@(#-r)&/@FromDigits[#,r=0~Range~9]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b738DGVtnGUE3fQUNZt0gTSLsV5ee6ZKZnlhRHK@sU2RrUBSXmpafWWcaq/Q8oyswr0XdIc3BNzsgHyiop6aCoroxVi1WrC05OzKur5qo21DGo1eGq1jXUsQTRekA@RMQYSHHV/gcA)

Input coefficients in descending order. Returns a 10x10 boolean matrix.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 78 bytes

```ruby
->c{(a=0..9).map{|y|a.map{|x|z=1;x==c.reduce{|s,x|s+x*z*=y}.to_i ? ?*:?.}*''}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcZBCoQgFADQq7irrD61rPh5kIhwnIIWUaSC5vfsxjDwFu@2H582TPWoQi6xAegKOOQVyJP8x9GD7eAQFdzr16o1kK4c6dLxh6OPYM5lZ4IJ3guIPMtiTJc1mm3T1FTsB9p5Ti8)

Returns an array of 10 strings

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 67 bytes

```ruby
->c{(a=0..9).map{|y|a.map{|x|z=1;x==c.reduce{|s,x|s+x*z*=y}.to_i}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y65WiPR1kBPz1JTLzexoLqmsiYRwqioqbI1tK6wtU3WK0pNKU1Ora4p1qmoKdau0KrSsq2s1SvJj8@sra39X6CQFh1toKMAQnqGsbH/AQ)

Return a matrix of booleans

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 42 bytes

```
p->matrix(10,,y,x,y--;floor(eval(p))==x--)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYrLCsIwEEV/ZZYzdkaSupKS/ogoZGFKINohFEm@Pvbhwt0591z1OcqkLYBrKuPLLzkWtIa5cuEqMoQ0zxmfH59QiZwrItS8aqqoICNoju9lTcNBimH7MdzQwgnqw66M1x0NQQcof7s5W7Nbv9nlF@7Uvg)